# How to improve performance when we have many methods in service to call

Tags: angular, performance

I have done a menu check system by retrieving information from each server that has products or not. If not, close the display of that menu.

My method is :
Create a service to check the products of each menu.
Run the service in the header (about 60 functions to execute)

Problem is :
The slowness of the system to retrieve all information from the system. It takes about 20 seconds to retrieve everything. (If in the products page)

My check product service.

```
countWhisky() {

  return this.http.post('/enviroment', {
    method: 'GET',
    uri: 'api url'
  })

}
 .
 .
 .
 about 60 function
```

My header component.ts

```
.
.
 private checkProduct: CheckProductsService,
.
.
ngAfterViewInit() {

    this.checkProduct.countSomething().subscribe((data: any) => {
    this.somethingCheck = data.record_set
  .
  .
  .
  about 60 subscribe
}
```

My header component.html

```
<li *ngIf="somethingCheck != ''">
  <a href="/products?brand=something">something</a>
</li>
.
.
about 60 ngIf
```

How do I improve the performance in angular 7.

Max Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think you should have a look to infinite scroll list and paginator (im using angular material paginator) for example you could render first 10 api and then when user refresh or changed the page, render another 10 api. Infinite scroll list looks like more useful for you.